# Minimum System Requirements to run Python & tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, system-requirements

I'm making a POS system using Tkinter for my Computing Programming Project and for the program analysis we have to talk about the proposed solution and how we'll go about carrying out the program. For this, it's recommended to talk about system requirements needed to run the program but I'm not very experienced in talking about system requirements so I'm not sure what numbers to mention in terms of RAM, CPU, storage, etc.

Could you give me some basic numbers that you'd expect a computer to have in order to run a POS program similar to this one?

[image]

Comment: If it can run minecraft above 20 fps your good to go

Comment: A POS is usually the only program running on the computer, so any basic machine can do the job. It's even more true if using a linux machine.